# Rename this site 'metta'?

Tags: feature-request

I thought it would promote better interactions if we changed 'meta' to metta. Realistically, having more compassion and perspective is what meta means, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree, since in the context of SE, "Meta" is not a Pali word. It comes from the **Greek** prefix. The same prefix is used in 'meta-physics' (what goes beyond physics), 'meta-literature' (the study of the study of literature), 'meta-linguistics', etc.

As Wiki says:

> Meta (from the Greek preposition and prefix meta- (μετά-) meaning "after", or "beyond") is a prefix used in English to indicate a concept which is an abstraction behind another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.

Of course, changing 'meta' in 'metta' would be a somewhat funny pun most would probably understand, but it would in fact not convey the meaning of the Greek and I don't think it's all it takes to promote loving kindness and compassion.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. But metta is "after or beyond" where many people feel that they currently are, so it seems applicable that way.

Answer (score 2):

That would indeed be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) -- i.e. it is not something which moderators can edit/implement, and it would instead require the SE site designers/developers/operators to make that change.

There have been [more than 20,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) feature request topics on SE. Now it's not that they don't implement any, and clearly they do implement some (nearly 3,000 of those 20,000 are [tagged "status-completed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-completed))  -- but I've never seen one being proposed and then implemented.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree fully with Tenzin Dorje's post I want to add that the meta-name/function is considered a *core element* within the Stack Exchange Network that needs to remain streamlined across SE's.

As an SE we are pretty open to changes but this is a bit too radical IMO.

Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Maybe metta should also be a core element in SE :-)